# From where can i get CTS hierarchy ? where does interface type fits in the CTS hierarchy

Tags: .net, value-type, reference-type

It says there are basically two types 1) Value type and reference type.
all value types are dereived from system.valuetype

1. Is there any thing like `system.referencetype` , because every CTS hierarchy i have seen shows two types below `system.objects` , a `Valuetype` and a `Referencetype`. My understanding is all types that are derieved from system.objects except `system.valuetype` are reference. Is this correct ?
2. And where does interface type fits in the hierarchy . Some diagrams it is show independently but in some it comes under the reference type .
3. From where can I get the actual CTS hierachy diagram ?

Answer (score 0):

Both reference and value types are derived from the ultimate base class Object. Interfaces are reference types.
this one is goor reference to CTS http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173104.aspx